# How to add address in marker google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My HTML Code is like this :

```
<a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="53#separator#-1.33#separator#Address 1">Button 1</a>
<a href="#" class="button" data-latLng="-34.397#separator#150.644#separator#Address 2">Button 2</a>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

My Javascript Code is like this :

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var latLng = $(this).attr("data-latLng");           
    initialize(latLng);

    function initialize(latLng) {
        console.log(latLng);
        latLng = latLng.split("#separator#");
        address = latLng[2];
        console.log(address);
        var map;        
        var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(latLng[0],latLng[1]);
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position:myCenter
        });

        var mapProp = {
            center: myCenter,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

        map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapProp);
        marker.setMap(map);

        ...
    };
    ...
});
```

Demo is like this : https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/b0ahcLxw/

I want display address in marker google map, but i'm still confused.
So when click the button, the map automatically displays the address on the marker.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not declare `infowindow` and `contentString` variable.
So you need to declare `infowindow` variable like bellow

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

And also declare `contentString`

```
var contentString ="Your Content String";
```

**Edit:**

```
// Add this line
var contentString ="Your Content String";
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    // Add this line
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    infowindow.setContent(contentString);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/vwyu4tth/2/)
Automatically show infowindow [JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/vwyu4tth/3/)

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. But that I wanted, address automatically appear without click marker. So when click the button, the map automatically direct displays the address on the marker.

Comment: I need you help. look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37209847/how-to-send-parameter-json-array-when-modal-open

Answer (score 0):

Add This line and in the place of hellooo set your content.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
infowindow.setContent("hellooo");
infowindow.open(map, marker);

});
```

else you can find here [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/b0ahcLxw/)

and for getting address from lat long you can use reverse geocoding 
you can find the example here with the code try this one
[Reverse Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)